# Slider value wont be any number besides 1 or 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using the Survival Shooter preset for Unity and trying to have a heart which is in the corner of the screen, cut off parts of it based on the players health.

I've tried setting the `Slider` value to the players `currentHealth / 100`, but it always just dissapears and the value is set to `0`.

I don't think it's a problem with my `Slider` as I can change the value in the editor and it works fine. I dont know what to do and Ive tried looking in other places.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

namespace CompleteProject
{
    public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int startingHealth = 100;                            // The amount of health the player starts the game with.
        public int currentHealth;                                   // The current health the player has.
        public Slider healthSlider;                                 // Reference to the UI's health bar.
        public Image damageImage;                                   // Reference to an image to flash on the screen on being hurt.
        public AudioClip deathClip;                                 // The audio clip to play when the player dies.
        public float flashSpeed = 5f;                               // The speed the damageImage will fade at.
        public Color flashColour = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.1f);     // The colour the damageImage is set to, to flash.


        Animator anim;                                              // Reference to the Animator component.
        AudioSource playerAudio;                                    // Reference to the AudioSource component.
        PlayerMovement playerMovement;                              // Reference to the player's movement.
        PlayerShooting playerShooting;                              // Reference to the PlayerShooting script.
        bool isDead;                                                // Whether the player is dead.
        bool damaged;                                               // True when the player gets damaged.


        void Awake ()
        {
            // Setting up the references.
            anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
            playerAudio = GetComponent <AudioSource> ();
            playerMovement = GetComponent <PlayerMovement> ();
            playerShooting = GetComponentInChildren <PlayerShooting> ();

            // Set the initial health of the player.
            currentHealth = startingHealth;
            healthSlider.value = 1;
        }


        void Update ()
        {
            // If the player has just been damaged...
            if(damaged)
            {
                // ... set the colour of the damageImage to the flash colour.
                damageImage.color = flashColour;
            }
            // Otherwise...
            else

            {
                // ... transition the colour back to clear.
                damageImage.color = Color.Lerp (damageImage.color, Color.clear, flashSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            // Reset the damaged flag.
            damaged = false;

            if (Input.GetKeyDown("k"))
            {
                TakeDamage(10);

            }
        }


        public void TakeDamage (int amount)
        {
            // Set the damaged flag so the screen will flash.
            damaged = true;

            // Reduce the current health by the damage amount.
            currentHealth -= amount;


            // Set the health bar's value to the current health.
            healthSlider.value = currentHealth/100;
            print(healthSlider.value);

            // Play the hurt sound effect.
            playerAudio.Play ();

            // If the player has lost all it's health and the death flag hasn't been set yet...
            if(currentHealth <= 0 && !isDead)
            {
                // ... it should die.
                Death ();
            }
        }


        void Death ()
        {
            // Set the death flag so this function won't be called again.
            isDead = true;

            // Turn off any remaining shooting effects.
            playerShooting.DisableEffects ();

            // Tell the animator that the player is dead.
            anim.SetTrigger ("Die");

            // Set the audiosource to play the death clip and play it (this will stop the hurt sound from playing).
            playerAudio.clip = deathClip;
            playerAudio.Play ();

            // Turn off the movement and shooting scripts.
            playerMovement.enabled = false;
            playerShooting.enabled = false;
        }


        public void RestartLevel ()
        {
            // Reload the level that is currently loaded.
            SceneManager.LoadScene (0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `currentHealth / 100f`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`currentHealth` is an `int` and so is `100`

so it will always be rounded to `0` (for `currentHealth < 100`) or `1` (for `100 <= currentHealth < 200`) using an `int` division when you do

```
 healthSlider.value = currentHealth / 100;
```

before the result is than parsed to `float` implicitly

---

to avoid that do

```
healthSlider.value = currentHealth / 100.0f;
```

to force it to use a `float` division.

Answer (score 0):

debug out currenthealth as an int the result will be an int, so 1/100 is 0

try making it `(float)currenthealth/100`